# Back up IIS 7 site settings

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

On a Windows Server 2008, I want to be able to restore site settings in IIS. Ie export the settings for every site.

How can I do this?

A lot stuff changed since I last did stuff like this (Like 6 years ago), so my knowledge on the options are a little outdated.

Comment: Does this cover your question?  http://serverfault.com/questions/9380/iis-7-backup-strategy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AppCMD add BACKUP <Backup_Name>
```

backups all the metafiles for IIS.  Archive these and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at a new tool coming from Microsoft that will allow you to do more than just backup. http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/346/web-deployment-tool/